# i have error for importing class related issue..already import class but "unknown type name" in xib project ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I import class in my class. But i got error when I try to create object of that class.
The error I got is **unknown type name "classname"**

for example image is attached

[image: error in my example]

Comment: Please check the class name in that `Yourplan.h`

Comment: Clean your project and check whether that the file exists in `BuildPhases` tab in `target` group

Comment: already done cleaning, and delete the derived data but not worked

Comment: Does your file `YourPlan.m` exists in `BuildPhases` tab in `Target` group

Comment: no,only xib's in buildPhase ,no other .h or .m file exixts

Comment: Add your .m file in BuildPhases

Comment: all the .m is in there..now what

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49151/discussion-between-kartik-bhatt-and-himanshu-joshi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a circular dependency/include. I think you also import welcomepage1 in YourPlan class Use a forward declaration (`@class YourPlan;`) rather than #importing the header.

either use `@class YourPlan` or import it in .m file

Answer (score 0):

you can't uses classes in circular dependency manner.

So, solution for that is...

you can't add this line in your header file.

```
#import "YourPlan.h"
```

but you add below line in your header file.

```
@class YourPlan;
```

and import this file in your welcomepage1.m file.

```
#import "YourPlan.h"
```

Comment: can you import your "YourPlan.h" file in .m file?

Comment: yes,i imported .h file .m file..and @class in .h file.....and memory allocation to object not permitted

Comment: import "YourPlan.h" file in your welcomepage1.m file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file exists is `BuildPhases` tab

[image]